# Can't connect to MySQL database from RIDE

Tags: python, mysql, robotframework, pymysql

I am trying connect to Mysql database from Ride (Robotframework) using below statement

```
Connect To Database Using Custom Params    pymysql    'pbds120_NO_RSA','username','password','10.x.x.x',3306
```

But I got the error: `2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'pbds120_NO_RSA' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)`

Are there anyone know this error ?

Comment: Looks like it expects the hostname or address as the first param.

Comment: When I move the hostname to first, I got another error "(2014, 'Command Out of Sync')"

Answer (score 0):

The keyword call is parsed as if the hostname to connect to is 'pbds120_NO_RSA', while it looks like you want to connect to '10.x.x.x'.

Check the [documentation of the library](https://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.5/DatabaseLibrary.html#Connect%20To%20Database%20Using%20Custom%20Params) - explicitly name the different arguments:

```
Connect To Database Using Custom Params    pymysql    database='pbds120_NO_RSA', user='username', password='password', host='10.x.x.x', port=3306
```

Comment: The parameter 'pbds120_NO_RSA' is db/schema name

Comment: Right - thus that value should be set to the correct argument, as in the sample call in my answer.